# In Resident Evil 4, why can't you dodge normal enemies like you can for bosses?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

In Resident Evil 4, it is possible to dodge bosses.

Why can't you dodge regular enemies, like Ganados?

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question. I've noticed a few of your questions have had good merit, but get voted down. Having a bit more text in your main text, and a well worded question title might help you with more up votes, and get your answers answered quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, bosses have attacks a lot more powerful, and have an effect on wider areas. Having the possibility to dodge through a QTE is a lot more needed against bosses than regular enemies, who can be dodged by simply walking away a few steps.
To have always to possibility to dodge any enemy would make the game a lot easier, and I guess it wasn't CAPCOM's objective.

Comment: I understand, as bosses deal a lot more damage than regular foes. Quicktime events are critical in boss scenarios!

Comment: There is a boss fight consisting only in QTE. This was really tough

Comment: Which one? Krauser knife fight? I think it is that one. If so, it is super hard, I hate the QTE when you get pushed down and have to button mash to keep Krauser from stabbing your chest. I have always detested button mash QTE's like the Boulder and Salazar statue ones because I cannot press fast enough.

Comment: K3nel, I do not really think I can classify the knife fight as a boss fight. You don' really kill Krauser. You just deter him and make him walk away with a cut on his chest with help from Ada. I think of the fight as a cutscene "test" that would prepare you for the difficulty of the real boss fight with him in the game later on. Even so, the cutscene's mash of QTE's are enough to leave you frustrated and maybe on the peak of rage-quitting.

Comment: Yeah, the mashing was pretty hard. On PC you fear for your keypad. And I only said Boss fight in the meaning that, well, you fight the boss.

Comment: Oh. I understand.